# StrictMode java.lang.Throwable: Untagged socket detected with AdMob

Tags: android, admob, android-strictmode

I am getting the following exception when using StrictMode with AdMob:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Untagged socket detected; use TrafficStats.setThreadSocketTag() to track all network usage
    at android.os.StrictMode.onUntaggedSocket(StrictMode.java:2012)
    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger.tag(NetworkManagementSocketTagger.java:78)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.tagSocket(BlockGuardOs.java:47)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:310)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:667)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketCreate(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:98)
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:484)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:547)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:139)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zza(Unknown Source:152)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zza(Unknown Source:788)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zzb(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabj.run(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagn.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzago.run(Unknown Source:9)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is similar to the issue in [StrictMode java.lang.Throwable: Untagged socket detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723973/strictmode-java-lang-throwable-untagged-socket-detected). However, the solution in that thread doesn't seem to work in this case.

I have added a call to TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag:

```
TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(ADS_THREAD_ID);

final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice(parent.getString(R.string.test_device_id))
    .build();
```

But the exception still seems to appear. It's like the thread that I am tagging is not the actual AdMob thread.

Any idea to how could I tag AdMob's thread?

Comment: As of today I think you still can't as admob spawns its own threads for http request and you can not setThreadStatsTag there.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same issue.